# How to update ENTRYPOINT program on a running pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod that uses an image ending with
`ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/myprogram"]` in its Dockerfile.
For debugging purposes I need to replace 'myprogram' written in golang with a new version of it on a running pod without killing the pod. I don't want to re-create the pod as it is a part of multi-component operator deployment. So, I would have to bring down all other deployments/pods, update the operator and then re-deploy everything, which I obviously reluctant to do for the sake of a quick debug.

In other pod we run a java program that's managed by `systemctl`, so when I need to patch it, I replace the jar and then restart the program with `systemctl restart`. All that inside a running pod, without restarting it and all the more without creating a new pod.

Is there any way to achieve this with the program run in the `ENTRYPOINT`?

Comment: You can't change the image `ENTRYPOINT` or Kubernetes `command:` dynamically.  The lifecycle of the container is exactly that single process, so once you stop the process the container exits too.  Can you `kubectl get -o yaml` an existing pod, tweak that pod spec (including changing its name and command), and `kubectl apply` the result to get a new pod?

Comment: It's either the operator or kubernetes through deployment controls the pod running. So, as soon as I delete the pod, a new one creates automatically. The kubectl apply would create a new pod which would be out of control of the operator or the deployment. So, I assume there would be 2 competing pods trying to start. Is any alternative to ENTRYPOINT that doesn't have the tie between the process and the container?